# Its not possible print items that have empty fields in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have this code below to scan all items in my users table and then print the name of each item.

And Im printing the field name of each item, and its working correctly when all items have the field name filled.

But when some item dont have the field name filled I got an error in print `r["name"]`.

Error: `key error "name"`

Do you know why I get this error? Dynamodb dont let us have empty fields? Or this isnt the correct way to get all items from a table?

Code:

```
dynamo = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
table = dynamo.get_table("users")
results = table.scan()
print results
for r in results:
    print r["name"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB is a schema-less database so, aside from the primary key and range key (if used) there are no required attributes for an item.  And DynamoDB does not support the idea of attributes with no value.  So, if you don't actually store a value for an attribute in an item, that attribute will not exist for that item.  And when you retrieve the object, that attribute will not exist in the returned item.

The way to handle this is to check if the item has an attribute or not before trying to access it:

```
for r in results:
    if 'name' in r:
        print(r['name'])
    else:
        print('{} has no name'.format(r))
```